# OpenCV - Morphological closing is removing image border

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, image-morphology

I have a really noisy image acquired from micro-tomography and I need to get the general shape to obtain the centroid as the alignment point. I am using the morphological closing with numerous iterations to get only one contour with good results but the operation is removing the border of the image; hence, I am losing data when the shape is not in the center.

I tried to use different border types but always I get the same result as you can see in images examples. Can I use this algorithm without lose the border data? Does there exist another way to get the centroid of these images?

The system must to be autonomous for different "noised shapes".

image examples:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xaalq70skq2fgm2/AABOnfvLKXteavCPMX42Zvzca?dl=0

Code:

```
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
i = j = 2

closing1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1.copy(), cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = i,\
                                borderType = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue = 0)
(_,contours1,_) = cv2.findContours(closing1.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

closing2 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh2.copy(), cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = j,\
                                borderType = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue = 0)
(_,contours2,_) = cv2.findContours(closing2.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


while len(contours1) != 1:
    i *= 2
    closing1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1.copy(), cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = i,\
                                borderType = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue = 0)
    (_,contours1,_) = cv2.findContours(closing1.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


while len(contours2) != 1:
    j *= 2
    closing2 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh2.copy(), cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = j,\
                                borderType = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue = 0)
    (_,contours2,_) = cv2.findContours(closing2.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: Please try without specifying the borderType, i.e.: `closing1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1.copy(), cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = i)` etc

Comment: Thanks! It's what I need!